# Selenium - How can I skip a testcase if is unnecessary

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, driver, testcase

I tried to skip the test case based on query result list size, but I get an error on tearDown and couldn't pass the test.

I need a way to set a PASSED result to the test case and follow to the next class.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses(value = {
        FirstTestClass.class,
        MaybeIsUnnecessary.class,
        ThirdTestClass.class
    }
public class Runner { }
```

Test class:

```
public class MaybeIsUnnecessary {

    @Test
    public void testGL11183AprovarContrato() {
        // do something
    }


    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Run a query HERE

        if (query results > 0 ) {
           // Continue the test
        }else{
           tearDown();
        }

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        // Need to finish the test and set 'Passed' Result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(someCondition());` inside method annotated with `@Before` annotation as shown below. It will ignore the method annotated with `@Test` annotation and pass the test.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {    
    org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(someCondition());    
}
```